# avc denied even with proper policy added

Tags: android, selinux

On AOSP build, I am getting following avc denied messages,

```
01-01 00:01:28.600    1458-1458/? W/iw﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:5): avc: denied { create } for scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tclass=netlink_socket permissive=0
01-01 00:01:28.660    1460-1460/? W/ndc﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:6): avc: denied { write } for name="netd" dev="tmpfs" ino=1575 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:netd_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
01-01 00:01:28.720    1461-1461/? W/ndc﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:7): avc: denied { write } for name="netd" dev="tmpfs" ino=1575 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:netd_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
01-01 00:01:28.790    1462-1462/? W/ndc﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:8): avc: denied { write } for name="netd" dev="tmpfs" ino=1575 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:netd_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
01-01 00:01:28.860    1463-1463/? W/ndc﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:9): avc: denied { write } for name="netd" dev="tmpfs" ino=1575 scontext=u:r:system_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:netd_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
```

Using the `audit2allow` I got following

```
allow system_app netd_socket:sock_file write; 
allow system_app self:netlink_socket create;
```

I have added the same to `device/<vendor-path>/sepolicy/system_app.te`
Also excluded system app from `neverallow` policy as below in `external/sepolicy/app.te`

```
neverallow { appdomain -system_app }
    self:{
        netlink_socket
        netlink_firewall_socket
        netlink_tcpdiag_socket
        netlink_nflog_socket
        netlink_xfrm_socket
        netlink_audit_socket
        netlink_ip6fw_socket
        netlink_dnrt_socket
    } *;
```

But still getting the same permission denied avc logs.

Comment: Are you getting the exact same audit failures after changing the te files?

Comment: How are you rebuilding and deploying? It might be worth while to check the size/checksum of `/sepolicy` on the device to ensure your changes are being propagated to the the initramfs.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot see anything wrong from your change. Suppose your sepolicy change was not building into kernel.
pls try make kernelclean and rebuild kernel, vim at the following file:

```
out/target/product/xxxx/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/policy.conf
```

All the sepolicy should in the policy.conf, grep your new adding policy to check if it has been compiled into kernel.